# AngularJS - How to use includes with variables?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to move recurring designs out of my angular template, in this case a header. The header template is as follows:

```
<div class="page-header">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    </div>
    <hr class="colorgraph hidden-print">
</div>
```

This template then is included every time I want to show a header, eg.

```
<div ng-init="title='Notes'" ng-include src="'/themes/templates/header.html'"></div>
<div ng-init="title='Other Notes'" ng-include src="'/themes/templates/header.html'"></div>
```

The problem I am running into is, that the ng-init of the last include is overwriting all others before that one and all headers are shown with the last title (here "Other Notes").

My approach is obvious wrong. What is the right way to do this? I am aware of [Angular Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), but I fail to understand the right way to use this for my problem.

Comment: You use directive inside another directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Angular Directives were indeed the right way. There is an option [transclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-wraps-other-elements) that does what I need:

header.html

```
<div class="page-header">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <h2 ng-transclude></h2>
    </div>
    <hr class="colorgraph hidden-print">
</div>
```

index.html

```
<heading>Create Booking</heading>
```

Directive definition:

```
app.directive('heading', function() {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: '/themes/templates/header.html'
    };
});
```

Transclude uses everything between the `heading` tag and compiles it under the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use directive,
Check how you write it,
NB: the code is not tested, I just give you the idea

header.html

```
<div class="page-header">
  <div class="clearfix">
  <h2>{{headerCtrl.title}}</h2>
 </div>
 <hr class="colorgraph hidden-print">
</div>
```

directive.js

```
angular.module("app", []);
angular.module("app")
 .directive("myHeader", myHeader);

function myHeader() {
 return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        title: '='
    },
    templateUrl: "header.html",
    controllerAs: "headerCtrl",
    bindToController: true,
    controller: function(){}
 };
}
```

your page:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">

<!-- here we use our directive
you can use ng-route and ng-view to have multiple pages and change
the title  in your page controller
 -->

 <my-header title="mytitle1"></my-header>
 <my-header title="mytitle2"></my-header>
<script src="link to AngularJs"></script>
<script src="directive.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```